# Parametric modelling of survival data: when there is no event in a long tail, is there information?

Tags: survival, modeling, nonparametric, kaplan-meier, heavy-tailed

I have a survival analysis question. Let's take a look at the below curve:

[image]

For the red curve, there are no more events after 48 months. For the black curve, there are no more events after 60-ish months.

Here's my question: when I'm fitting parametric distributions to the data, does this long right tail post 48 and 60-ish months for red and black, respectively, contribute to the model?

My thinking is no. There is no event to fit data to so the curves fit data to the last step. Whether this tail extends to 96 months or 9600 months would not change the parametric model. Whether there were 3 people or 30 people censored post 48 or 60-ish months does not matter to the parametric model if there are no events.

Can you help me?

Comment: Yes, all data contribute to the estimation. This is one of those situations in which you may prefer to focus on Restricted Mean Survival, flexible approaches for parametric estimation of the survival curve, or quantile approaches. Apologies I have no time right now for a detailed response, so I am just providing here few references:https://www2.le.ac.uk/Members/pl4/workshop2011-1/Stockholm-Workshop-2011-Paul-Lambert.pdf ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24314264 ; http://journals.lww.com/epidem/Fulltext/2012/09000/Evaluating_Percentiles_of_Survival.24.aspx